# Route Domain to two IP's

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing

I am looking to route domain.com to one X.X.X.1 and domain.com/blog to X.X.X.2. Is there a way this can be accomplished? if so how would one accomplish it?

Can a DNS accomplish this or do I need a load balancer (like ngix I have used a bit in the past) or something?

For a bit more detail, domain.com is a spring boot application and domain.com/blog is a wordpress application. Both have the exact same UI's but currently are on different domains. I know there is the following but I dont really want to re-write my front end for the blog.

org.kamranzafar.spring.wpapi
spring-wpapi-client
Thanks in advance, Brian

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done in DNS as the http protocol dies not support srv or Txt records, relying g on the OS to convert domain names to IP addresses.

As you suspect, the way to do this is by using a load balancer or equivalent. The way this is typically done in Apache is with ProxyPass rules. As you did not specify a web server that's as specific as I can get.

An alternative would be to use blog.domain.com with different DNS, assuming that this server is externally reachable.

Comment: Hello, I thought about doing blog.domain.com, but wont the search engines consider that an entirely different website? Meaning will blog.domain.com will have a different pagerank than domain.com?

Answer (score 0):

`domain.com` and `domain.com/blog` are the same domain so no way to assign different IP addresses.

But you could link from `domain.com/` to `X.X.X.2/blog` instead of `domain.com/blog`.

Better may be to use a subdomain like blog.domain.com.